# column names in R - substitute part of name string

Tags: r

I have `X745.971008.Nanometers` as col names and can't figure out how to make it in the format:

I want col names thus: `745.971008_nm`

or better, with the wavelength rounded to 3 dp: `745.971_nm`

I have tried: `names(df) <- sub('X\\.+(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\.Nanometers\\.', '\\1_nm', names(df))`

and: `colnames(df) <- gsub("X(.+).Nanometers.", "\\1_nm", colnames(df))`

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this, try using `rename_all` and `str_replace_all`.

I guess this would be the most accurate way since it rounds the values in the variable names like you requested:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  'X745.971008.Nanometers' = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  'X743.971999.Nanometers' = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  stack() %>% 
  mutate(ind = str_replace(ind, 'X', ''),
         ind = str_replace(ind, '.Nanometers', ''),
         ind = paste(round(as.numeric(ind), digits = 3), '_nm')) %>%  
  unstack(df2, form = values~ind) %>% 
  rename_all(
    funs(
      stringr::str_replace_all(., 'X', '')
    )
  ) %>% 
  rename_all(
    funs(
      stringr::str_replace_all(., '._', '_')
    )
  )

#>   743.972_nm 745.971_nm
#> 1          1          1
#> 2          2          2
#> 3          3          3
#> 4          4          4
#> 5          5          5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**OR**

```r
df <- data.frame(
  'X745.971008.Nanometers' = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  'X743.971999.Nanometers' = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  rename_all(
    funs(
      stringr::str_replace_all(., 'X', '')
    )
  ) %>% 
  rename_all(
    funs(
      stringr::str_replace_all(., '.Nanometers', '_nm')
    )
  )

#>   745.971008_nm 743.971999_nm
#> 1             1             1
#> 2             2             2
#> 3             3             3
#> 4             4             4
#> 5             5             5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**OR**

```r
df <- data.frame(
  'X745.971008.Nanometers' = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  'X743.971999.Nanometers' = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  rename_all(
    funs(
      stringr::str_replace_all(., 'X', '')
    )
  ) %>% 
  rename_all(
    funs(
      stringr::str_replace_all(., '\\d\\d\\d.Nanometers', '_nm')
    )
  )

#>   745.971_nm 743.971_nm
#> 1          1          1
#> 2          2          2
#> 3          3          3
#> 4          4          4
#> 5          5          5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub` :

```
x <- 'X745.971008.Nanometers'
sub('X(\\d+\\.\\d+).Nanometers', '\\1_nm', x)
#[1] "745.971008_nm"
```

In case of column names try :

```
colnames(df) <- sub('X(\\d+\\.\\d+).Nanometers', '\\1_nm', colnames(df))
```

---

If you want to round the values :

```
paste0(round(as.numeric(sub('X(\\d+\\.\\d+).Nanometers', '\\1',x)), 3), '_nm')
#[1] "745.971_nm"
```